# Date Generation in sql from two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a view that will count Active and Ceased Services. I have two dates that i am using, the Put into Service date and the ceased date. For services that are ceased the column will be populated. So I have to create a monthly trend for active and ceased orders. Basically at a specific month i have to count what was active and what was ceased for the different months. the query should be able to generate the months from the Put into service date to the ceased date. this is how the data is:

```
Region|Service No|Type Of Service|Put Into Service Date|Ceased Date
GP    |123456    |Mobile         |15/02/2014           |12/05/2018
GP    |124578    |Mobile         |15/02/2017           |NULL
```

Expected Results:

```
  Region|Services To Date|Type Of Service|Report Month|Active Services|Ceased Services
  GP    |1               |Mobile         |01/03/2014  |1              |0 
  GP    |1               |Mobile         |01/04/2014  |1              |0 
  GP    |1               |Mobile         |01/05/2014  |1              |0
```

So there should be one row for every month that the service is active up until the service is ceased. So when the report runs on 01/06/2018 it should pick up that the 123456 service no is now ceased. so when the report runs it will look like this:

```
Region|Services To Date|Type Of Service|Report Month|Active Services|Ceased Services
GP    |2               |Mobile         |01/06/2018  |1              |1
```

Take note that the data goes as far back as 2013 so for me to manually create the monthly rows will be a challenge.

Comment: what does the `Services To Date` stand for?

Comment: thats the total number of services that were Put Into Service at some point. its a count on the service no. The value should be incremental as more services are Put into Service and the active services will be counting the services that do not have a ceased date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Things you dont need**: mytesttable should be replaced (in stored procedure code) with your real table name.

**with** mytesttable:

```
create table mytesttable (
Region Nvarchar(2),
Service_No INT,
TypeOfService Nvarchar(20),
PutIntoService DATE,
Ceased Date)

INSERT INTO mytesttable VALUES
('GP',123456,'Mobile'     ,'2014-02-15'       ,'2018-05-12'),
('GP',124578,'Mobile'     ,'2017-02-15'       ,NULL)
```

Create a *stored procedure*:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE report_ceased_monthly (@START DATE, @END DATE) AS 
begin


IF @START IS NULL
SELECT      @START  = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
IF @END IS NULL
SELECT      @END    = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))



CREATE TABLE #MYMONTHS (MONTHFIRST DATE)

DECLARE DATELOOP CURSOR FOR
SELECT @END
OPEN DATELOOP

FETCH NEXT FROM DATELOOP INTO @END

WHILE @END >= @START
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #MYMONTHS
SELECT @END
SELECT @END = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @END)
END
CLOSE DATELOOP
DEALLOCATE DATELOOP

SELECT  [Region],
        SUM(CASE WHEN M.MONTHFIRST >= PUTINTOSERVICE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Service To Date],
        [TypeOfService],
        M.MONTHFIRST [Report Month],
        SUM(CASE --CHECK THIS EDIT TOO
                WHEN ([CEASED] IS NULL OR [CEASED] >= M.MONTHFIRST)
                AND PutIntoService <= M.MONTHFIRST
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) [Active Services],
        SUM(CASE
                WHEN MONTH([CEASED]) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, M.MONTHFIRST))
                     AND YEAR([CEASED]) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, M.MONTHFIRST))
                     AND [CEASED] IS NOT NULL
                     AND PutIntoService <= M.MONTHFIRST
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) [Ceased Services]
FROM mytesttable T, #MYMONTHS M
GROUP BY    [Region],
            [TypeOfService],
            M.MONTHFIRST

ORDER BY [Report Month] DESC

end
```

Then execute it:

```
EXEC report_ceased_monthly @START = '2018-01-01', @END = '2018-06-01'
```

EDIT: CUSTOM VARIABLE ASSIGNEMENT

```
DECLARE @CUSTOMSTART DATE
SELECT @CUSTOMSTART = (SELECT MIN(PutIntoService) FROM MYTESTTABLE)

EXEC report_ceased_monthly @START = @CUSTOMSTART, @END = '2018-06-01'
```

Output:

```
Region Service To Date TypeOfService        Report Month Active Services Ceased Services
------ --------------- -------------------- ------------ --------------- ---------------
GP     2               Mobile               2018-06-01   1               1
GP     2               Mobile               2018-05-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2018-04-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2018-03-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2018-02-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2018-01-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2017-12-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2017-11-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2017-10-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2017-09-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2017-08-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2017-07-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2017-06-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2017-05-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2017-04-01   2               0
GP     2               Mobile               2017-03-01   2               0
GP     1               Mobile               2017-02-01   1               0
GP     1               Mobile               2017-01-01   1               0
```

Comment: Thanks but the services to date should be incremental because its tracking all the services that were put into service irrespective of whether its Put into Service or Ceased.

Comment: so `[Service To Date]` is the total of `[Ceased Services] + [Active Services]` in the selected month?

Comment: is possible to select the start date as the min date from the table i am reading from and the end date can be the 1st day of the current month? I know how to build the query but when include it like this: EXEC report_ceased_monthly START = (SELECT MIN(Put into Service date) , END = (SELECT MAX(Ceased Date) FROM table) it throws an error. I removed the  @ on this comment

Comment: you cant use a subquery in order to assign a value to a stored procedure parameter. check the edit